# Create dynamic content in my modal in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently working on someone's website and I created 6 different modals for each product. But I would like to insert his content in each modal when I click on the modal button.

So far I've done this:

```
function produits(tag, nom, price, imagesrc, description){
 this.Tag = tag;
 this.Nom = nom;
 this.Price = price;
 this.SRC = imagesrc;
 this.Description = description;
}

var produit = [];

//6x for my 6 products 
produit.push(new produits(1, "nom", 35, "path/to/img","Description"));

In html I created my modals 6x this way 
<button type="button" id="bouton" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Add to cart</button>

                <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                  <div class="modal-dialog">

                    <div class="modal-content">
                      <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

Now I would like to add the content of my 6 products that I stored in my array into my modals. Can someone help me with this please?

Thank you very much in advance.

John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this fiddle [modal dynamic content using javascript](https://jsfiddle.net/lamp03/ewvsf2x8/1/).

In this i have passed product index as 1. You can test it by creating array for 5 more products and passing index as 2,3,4,5 and 6 respectively.

Note that I have called showProduct() function on click of button.

HTML :

```
<button type="button" id="bouton" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="showProduct(1);">Add to cart</button>

            <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
              <div class="modal-dialog">

                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                    <div class="row">
                    <span><b>Product tag : </b></span><span id="product_tag"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                    <span><b>Product nom : </b></span>
                      <span id="product_nom"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                     <span><b>Product price : </b></span>
                    <span id="product_price"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                    <span><b>Product image : </b></span>
                    <img id="product_image" src=""/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                    <span><b>Product description : </b></span>
                    <span id="product_description"></span>
                    </div>

                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Javascript :-

```
    function produits(tag, nom, price, imagesrc, description){
 this.Tag = tag;
 this.Nom = nom;
 this.Price = price;
 this.SRC = imagesrc;
 this.Description = description;
}

var produit = [];

//6x for my 6 products 
produit.push(new produits(1, "nom", 35, "path/to/img","Description"));

function showProduct(productId){
    document.getElementById("product_tag").innerHTML = produit[productId-1].Tag;
  document.getElementById("product_nom").innerHTML = produit[productId-1].Nom;
  document.getElementById("product_price").innerHTML = produit[productId-1].Price;
  document.getElementById("product_image").src = produit[productId-1].SRC;
  document.getElementById("product_description").innerHTML = produit[productId-1].Description;
}
```

Comment: What's the [productId-1] ? @Lalit

Comment: @JohnSimmons Its the index or position at which product is added in your  product array. I have named it productId you can rename it to product index. Like you want to display product information of 6 products then you can pass the values of product index as 1,2,3,4,5 and 6 on click event of button.

Comment: @JohnSimmons We have added first product in your product array. So it will be added at index 0. Now we are passing 1 as product index in on click event of button, so we are subtracting 1 from the passed index i.e. "1" to get the position of this product in product array which is "0". In given example it will be [1-1].